How to write this X=1 to L with curvy brackets in LaTeX? (image included)
 is what I need to write. This is from "Introduciton to Statistical Learning" textbook, which is in pdf format. Here's what I now have, $\{X_l\}^{L}$, I have not been able to get to display 1 right and this is how it is displayed currently. 

Welcome to TeX.SE! You almost done, you only need to ad _{1}, i.e. write $\X_l\}^{L}_{1}$ ... . More about how to write math with LaTeX see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

@Zarko, ${X_{\ell}}_1^{L}$ did it. I thought there was some other way to write 1 and L, but I missed this simple way. Thanks.

Use \ell for the loopy l and _{1} for the subscript 1

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$
\{X_{\ell}\}_{1}^{L}
$
\end{document}

